# Express project run error in cpanel terminal

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I am trying to run NodeJS app in cPanel terminal but I have getting this error. I am new in cPanel. How can I solve this

```
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9336
      return await WebAssembly.instantiate(mod, {
                               ^

RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
    at lazyllhttp (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9336:32)

Node.js v20.3.1
```